# Why is the output half of what it should be?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

```
dtype('float32')
arr.nbytes
```

*Output-*16
Similarly for a datatype 'float 64',the datasize is 32.
I am confused as to why is this happening? Shouldn't it be 32 and 64?

Comment: `nbytes` returns *array size*. Try `dtype(np.float32).itemsize`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's your `arr`, exactly?

```
In [7]: np.array([], dtype='float32').nbytes                                                                                                                  
Out[7]: 0

In [8]: np.array([1], dtype='float32').nbytes                                                                                                                 
Out[8]: 4

In [9]: np.array([1, 2, 3, 4], dtype='float32').nbytes                                                                                                        
Out[9]: 16
```

Seems consistent to me. 4 * 8 == 32, 4 * (4 * 8) == 16. You probably confuse array size and "type size".  Also, size is measured in bytes, not bits.